# How to map data with VS2012 SSDT project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to investigate how to work with SSDT properly. Currently I made publish working however I can not understand how to use this tool for development.
What I mean is that I can change the code, but how to see the actual result? I can add database to Object explorer and execute the statement, but how can I save it to the project after I made some changes?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the way I work with SSDT is to have a local database instance (Sql Express, Developer or LocalDb) and use that to push your changes to locally to test against and then when you are ready you can push your changes to the dev/test/prod server.

To actually run the code you will need to deploy it to a sql server, ssdt basically gives you what a compiler would give you - to run the actual code you need sql.

I would also investigate using tSQLt to write unit tests then you can push the project and the tests to your local instance and use that to check the data against the model.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working in SSDT, the changes that you make are to model. You then need to deploy these changes by doing a diff using the schema compare. The schema compare will do a diff between the model and target and prepare an upgrade script for you.

Try hte following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: As I said that I know how to publish already. The question is: Is it possible to map the model to real data to see all the results I made before I publish the project?

Comment: The model does not persist the data. If you are wanting to save data in regards to initial data for tables after a deployment, then you could create a post deployment script that could seed your database.